# Save html div in high resolution png

Tags: javascript, png

I am saving an image in a HTML `div` element called `mynetwork` as png. I have a button that allows to download said image.

Here is my code

```
  var button = document.getElementById('btn-download');
  button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      var dataURL = document.getElementById('mynetwork').src;
      button.href = dataURL;
  });
```

Here is the beginning of the content of dataURL

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAACGgAAAaQCAYAAAA9zvqqAAAgAElEQVR4XuzdP2rTcRzH4W9S14KHEKyTRxBHseoxbFMFr+ANREj8s3gEKcTVwSPoAZwtdZA
```

However, the downloaded image is pretty low resolution. How can I increase its resolution, so that the downloaded image is high resolution?

Comment: it's the same exact file as what you're displaying isn't it?

Comment: yes indeed, however I don't read from a png file, I generate the image using vis.js